# How can I define in a DB first POCO model, a field that is both PK and FK together

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity-framework-6

Table `EMPLOYEE` has `MST_SQ` (master-sequence) as both it's primary key, and as an FK to the primary key of table `MASTER`, which is also named `MST_SQ`. This table is used to join several other tables as well so that they all have the same PK. That is as far as my understanding goes.

I need to defined a 1 to 1 relationship in my model between class `Employee` and class `Master`, but I simply cannot find a way to do this. It seems only relationships with multiplicty allow an FK field to be speficied, and those that look like for 1 to 1, e.g. has optional(...)..WithRequiredPrincipal(....) has no FK space.

I could do some manual coding to link `EMPLOYEE` and `MASTER` when the are loaded, but how could I tell they were loaded. Is there any event that signals a POCO being populated from the DB? Or, the real question, how do I define this relationship in code?

Answer (score 1):

From [Relationships and Navigation Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564) :

> When working with 1-to-1 or 1-to-0..1 relationships, there is no
>   separate foreign key column, the primary key property acts as the
>   foreign key

From [Configuring a Required-to-Optional Relationship (One-to–Zero-or-One)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620#RequiredToOptional) :

> because the name of the property does not follow the convention the
>   HasKey method is used to configure the primary key

```
public class Master
{
    public int MST_SQ { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int MST_SQ { get; set; }

    public virtual Master Master { get; set; }
}
```

The Employee has the MST_SQ property that is a primary key and a foreign key:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Master>().HasKey(m => m.MST_SQ);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().HasKey(e => e.MST_SQ);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
                .HasRequired(e => e.Master) //Employee is the Dependent and gets the FK
                .WithOptional(m => m.Employee); //Master is the Principal
}
```

Generated migration code:

```
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Employees",
            c => new
                {
                    MST_SQ = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.MST_SQ)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Masters", t => t.MST_SQ)
            .Index(t => t.MST_SQ);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Masters",
            c => new
                {
                    MST_SQ = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.MST_SQ);
```

So you don't need the "FK space" because EF makes it the foreign key without you having to specify it